# Long Article - How to improve UX & Readability

Tags: long

We are creating a few very, very long articles (4000 - 6000 words) for our website and I am wondering what I can do to make it easier for readers to navigate it and decide what to read and what to skip.

My idea so far is to structure each article very well with headings and subheadings and include a table of contents like:

```
1.0 Introduction
2.0 Why you need XYZ
   2.1 Subtitle something...
3.0 ...
```

Do you have any other ideas of what I could do to improve the experience?

Most importantly, do you have some example websites that have implemented great UX for long articles and have implemented table of contents in clever ways?

I have seen a website before that had a TOC sidebar, which highlighted where you are. That was very clever, do you know any other websites that are doing something similar?

Please also post your experience of what to avoid and not do like pagination :)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the content and the reader.

Often Google documentation has ability to be content rich but feel very accessible. [Material design docs](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html) is an example, note the [Layout > Structure page](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#) is more than 1800 words long.

Design points:

- well structured content (including multiple pages)
- simple *first level only* TOC
- generous use of white space
- only content (no artifices)
- use of graphics, with regimented layout
- page hight not an issue

Also would be remiss not to add *brevity helps with UX*.  Make the article closer to 400 words than 4000 if possible. Consider a series of articles.

Answer (score 0):

The important things, in my opinion, are to:

- Keep things clean.

  - Eliminate distracting elements from your page.
  - Much use of white space.
  - Alternate between various sizes of text, for example, using big headers between pieces of text will let the user focus on only one piece, **don't overdo it though**.
- Make sure the table of contents is accesible all the time without having to scroll up, show it constantly as a fixed sidebar or let the user collapse it.
- Show clarifications (eg: words) aside your text.

More general tips:

- Clarify unknown words
- Summarize the text at the end.

In my opinion, a nice site to read is [The Magic of CSS by Adam Schwartz](http://adamschwartz.co/magic-of-css/)